# ESP8266 stops connecting to NTP server when set up to run WiFi Manager

Tags: wifi, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have an ESP8266 that connects to WiFi and then calls an NTP server to get the time. Originally, I had set up the WiFi connection to work off a "config.h" file with SSID and password - the vanilla approach. Later, I set up a WiFi Manager with the AsyncWebServer library to avoid hardcoding credentials as shown in this [tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-wi-fi-manager-asyncwebserver/) by Rui Santos .

Now the user enters WiFi credentials on a web-page hosted by the ESP8266 which provides a Wireless Access Point. These credentials are stashed away in files on the local file-system (LittleFS) and accessed when making the WiFi connection from that point onwards. Upon connecting, the ESP8266 runs a web-server that hosts a static web-page.

This works fine and the ESP8266 connects to WiFi BUT the NTP service no longer works! I get a fixed time ~ 12:00 midnight from the NTP client. When I revert to connecting to WiFi the vanilla way, the NTP service works as expected.

Here is my code for making the WiFi connection in station mode. The  class `GuruWebServer` has methods `initializeaLittle()`, `readaLittle()` and `writeaLittle()` for file-system operations. The key method, `initializeWiFi()`, returns `true` when connection is successfully made with the credentials stashed away in the file-system and returns `false` otherwise. The method has a loop with `millis()` in which the attempt to connect to WiFi is made until timeout (e.g. 60s).

I observe that the SSID and password are correctly recorded and WiFi connection is successfully made. Subsequently, using LanScan (on Mac), I can see the ESP8266 at the station IP address as configured. Using a browser, I can load the web-page it serves. However, I am no longer able to get the time-and-date from calling the NTP service.

```
bool GuruWebServer::initializeWiFi() {
    /*
    * Make WiFi connection when SSID and PWD are available
    * and set up station for web-service.
    */
    // Initialize LittleFS
    this->initializeaLittle();

    // Connect to WiFi
    this->readaLittle(&SSID, Path2_SSID); 
    this->readaLittle(&PWD, Path2_PWD);
    this->readaLittle(&IP, Path2_IP);
    this->readaLittle(&Gateway, Path2_Gateway);
    String conn_ack = (String)"SSID <" + SSID + "> | PWD <" + PWD + "> | IP <" + IP + "> | Gateway <" + Gateway + ">";

    if (SSID == "" || PWD == "") {  // Files not populated!
        Serial.println("Found NO SSID or PWD!");
        return false;
    }

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    localIP.fromString(IP.c_str());
    localGateway.fromString(Gateway.c_str());

    if (!WiFi.config(localIP, localGateway, subnet)) {
        Serial.println("Configured NO station!");
        return false;
    }
    WiFi.begin(SSID, PWD);

    unsigned long _now   = millis();
    unsigned long _then  = _now;    // Marker for ticker
    unsigned long _stop  = _now;    // Marker for timeout
    unsigned long delta_minor = 0;  // Time since last tick
    unsigned long delta_major = 0;  // Time since start
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
        _now = millis();
        delta_minor = _now - _then; // Time since last tick
        delta_major = _now - _stop; // Time since start

        if (delta_minor > 1000) {   // Mark time and reset delta
            _then = _now;
            Serial.print (".");
        }
        if (delta_major > 60000) {  // Stop attempting connection
            String timely = (String)"Now " + _now + " Stop " + _stop + " Diff " + delta_major;
            Serial.println(timely);
            Serial.println("Made NO WiFi connection!");
            return false;           // Exit false
        }                           // end IF
    }                               // end WHILE WiFi 

    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    return true;
}
```

To get time, I have used NTPClient library in the main program as follows:

```
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
WiFiUDP NTP_UDP;
NTPClient timeClient(NTP_UDP, "us.pool.ntp.org");
```

and in the `setup()` function of "main.cpp", I have:

```
  // Connect to  the NTP client
  delay(500);
  timeClient.begin();
  timeClient.setTimeOffset(-18000); // Central time GMT-5 ~ -5 x 3600 
  timeClient.update();
  Serial.println(timeClient.getFormattedTime());
```

The github branch [rev007](https://github.com/sunbee/ShowMeState/tree/rev007) has the code with WiFi Manager and [rev006](https://github.com/sunbee/ShowMeState/tree/rev006) has the vanilla WiFi.

I have tried the following:

1. Used a different approach to get time on ESP8266 with "time.h" and `configTime()` function.
2. Configured the web-server to use a port other than 80 (e.g. 8211) in `AsyncWebServer server(80);`.

Grateful for any help figuring this out, thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have simplified the code to illustrate the problem. This single script sets up the ESP8266 as WiFi station. The device connects to WiFi successfully but is unsuccessful calling the NTP service.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "LittleFS.h"

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
WiFiUDP NTP_UDP;
NTPClient timeClient(NTP_UDP, "pool.ntp.org");
// Alt.

#include "config.h"

IPAddress localIP;
IPAddress localGateway;
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  // Comment out from here --->
  localIP.fromString(IP);
  localGateway.fromString(Gateway);

  if (!WiFi.config(localIP, localGateway, subnet)) {
    Serial.println("Configured NO station!");
  }
  // <--- upto here!
  WiFi.begin(SSID, PWD);

  unsigned long _now   = millis();
  unsigned long _then  = _now;    // Marker for ticker
  unsigned long _stop  = _now;    // Marker for timeout
  unsigned long delta_minor = 0;  // Time since last tick
  unsigned long delta_major = 0;  // Time since start
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    _now = millis();
    delta_minor = _now - _then;   // Time since last tick
    delta_major = _now - _stop;   // Time since start

    if (delta_minor > 1000) {     // Mark time and reset delta
        _then = _now;
        Serial.print (".");
    } 
    if (delta_major > 60000) {    // Stop attempting connection
        String timely = (String)"Now " + _now + " Stop " + _stop + " Diff " + delta_major;
        Serial.println(timely);
        Serial.println("Made NO WiFi connection!");
    }                             // end IF
  }                               // end WHILE WiFi 

  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Connect to  the NTP client
  delay(3000);
  timeClient.begin();
  timeClient.setTimeOffset(-18000); // Central time GMT-5 ~ -5 x 3600 

  delay(3000);
  timeClient.update();
  Serial.println(timeClient.getFormattedTime());
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

When I comment out the code as shown so as not to configure the IP address from settings but let it be determined at run-time, then all is well.

[image: NTP Call SUCCESS]

Comment: Why you have two `reset_cursor()` with the same function signature? Your `reset_cursor()` doesn’t do reset  cursor but one set the time based on NTP and another reset it to a specific date which might explain why you get a fixed time. BTW, ESP implements its own NTP via its lwIp stack, so you don’t need the external NTPClient library.

Comment: When writing a function, the function should perform one and only one function as described by its name, if a function is to reset cursor, then don’t add set time into it….

Comment: @hcheung Thanks for looking through my code. I commented out the `reset_cursor()` function in the `void setup()` routine and instead connected directly to the NTP server - both using the client and the direct method. I still have the same issue, so we can rule out `reset_cursor()` as the cause. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @hcheung I have simplified the code now to illustrate the issue in isolation from other features of the app, Thank you.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem to the WiFi station configuration with IP, Gateway and subnet. If instead of configuring the IP address, I let the system determine the IP address  to use at runtime by commenting out the WiFi configuration part of the code`WiFi.config(localIP, localGateway, subnet)`, then the external service calls are successful with the web-server running. Only disadvantage is the IP address of the ESP8266 is not known upfront and I need to find it out by LanScan (on Mac) or by print statement to serial. Any reason for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious enough to try your code. The issue is without the proper DNS setup, the NTP(UDP) won't be able to resolve the NTP name "pool.ntp.org", I tested your code with slightly modification and simplification. Without specifying the DNS with `WiFi.config(localIP, localGateway, subnet)`, the `timeClient.update()` simply can't establish a NTP connection, by adding a DNS IP to `WiFi.config(localIP, localGateway, subnet, dns)`, the following code works like a charm.

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

WiFiUDP NTP_UDP;
NTPClient timeClient(NTP_UDP, "pool.ntp.org");

#include "config.h"

IPAddress localIP(192, 168, 0, 120);     // my local ip
IPAddress localGateway(192, 168, 0, 1);  // my local gateway
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress dns(1, 1, 1, 1);               // CloudFlare DNS server

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(SSID, PWD);
  WiFi.config(localIP, localGateway, subnet, dns);
  int count = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    if (count++ > 20) ESP.restart();  //timeout, reboot
  } 
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Connect to  the NTP client
  timeClient.begin();
  timeClient.setTimeOffset(8*3600);  //my timezone
  if (timeClient.update())
    Serial.println(timeClient.getFormattedTime());
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying out my code and modifying it. I added the DNS line with my IP and Gateway but still have the issue. I am on a Mac and got the Gateway and subnet mask from the network settings. Those are the settings I should be using, right? It didn't resolve the issue for me. In fact, I added code to make a REST API call to zipcodeAPI.com and that also didn't work. The only thing that works for me is to comment out the IP config and live with the fact that I need to discover the IP address of ESP each time it restarts. Thanks again for your efforts, appreciate it and upvoted.

Comment: The example is based on my localIP, yours might be different. From your screen shot, I can see that your local network is on different subnet 192.168.1.xxx from my 192.168.0.xxx.

Answer (score 1):

If you want using WiFiManager just leave `wifiManager.setSTAStaticIPConfig` and use this after `wifiManager.autoConnect`

```
WiFi.begin();
WiFi.config(IPAddress(192, 168, 1, 148), IPAddress(192, 168, 1, 1), IPAddress(192, 168, 1, 1), IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));
```

It working for me on ESP8266.